# geom_sf mapping points/shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf, tigris

I am using the Tigris package to download shape files with the code,

```
options(tigris_class = "SF")
```

While I can easily map polygons

```
ggplot(data=zctas) +
  geom_sf(aes())
```

I am struggling to create a marker/point instead of a filled polygon (for example, a shape -- like a circle inside a zctas) as the shape file I've pulled down from tigris does not have a lat/long for the x and y AES mapping. The shape file has a "geometry" column, and I am wondering if I can use that?

The documentation here, https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html

appears to indicate the geom_sf can be used go create points? (I am guessing using the centroid of the zctas' polygon?) but I haven't been able to find an example? 
Grateful for any resources to identify code that maps points from this Tigris generated shape-file, and or tips and/or alternative approaches.

Comment: I am afraid it seems as if you haven't produced a fully reproducible example - your ggplot call does not work for me. Could you try to run your own code in a entirely new session and post the possibly missing information please? Thanks

Comment: I added a fully reproducible example to my answer. @JaneA, I suggest you edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you may just need to transform your data into points with the `st_centroid()` function... at the most basic, like this:

```
ggplot(data=st_centroid(zctas)) +
  geom_sf()
```

Or perhaps:

```
ggplot(data=st_centroid(st_geometry(zctas))) +
  geom_sf()
```

For more details and examples, see: 
https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for `stat_sf_coordinates()`, described [here.](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_sf_coordinates.html)

```r
library(ggplot2)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/sf/shape/nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf() +
  stat_sf_coordinates()
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may
#> not give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(
    aes(color = SID74, size = AREA, geometry = geometry),
    stat = "sf_coordinates"
  ) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "C") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may
#> not give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

One comment about the `geometry = geometry` statement inside the `aes()` call of the last example: Both `geom_sf()` and `stat_sf_coordinates()` will auto-map the geometry column if they find one in the dataset. However, `geom_point()` doesn't know about geometry columns and therefore doesn't automap, thus we have to map manually.